# SQS Filter Policy for nested array object property

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

Imagine I have these two events:

```json
// event 1
{
    "events": [
        {
            code: "foo",
            type: "TYPE_1"
        },
        {
            code: "bar",
            type: "TYPE_2"
        }
    ]
}
```

```json
// event 2
{
    "events": [
        {
            code: "xpto",
            type: "TYPE_3"
        },
        {
            code: "osld",
            type: "TYPE_4"
        }
    ]
}
```

I would like to build a policy filter that would accept a message if it has **any** event with `type: TYPE_1`. Something like: `"events": { "any": ["$.type", "TYPE_1"] }`. So it would receive the `event 1` but not the `event 2`.

Is it possible with SQS filter policy alone?

Answer (score 1):

Message Attributes consists of Name, Type and Value. Type can be, String, String.Array, Number, and Binary. See doc [Amazon SNS message attributes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-message-attributes.html)

Knowing that, then you can build your Message Attribute with String.Array listing all types present at the message. Like this:

```json
{
  "MessageAttributes": {
    "types": {
      "Type": "String.Array",
      "Value": ["TYPE_1","TYPE_2", "TYPE_N"]
    }
  }
}
```

At this point, then you can build a filter policy to get only messages containing `TYPE_1`:

```json
  {
    "types": ["TYPE_1"]
  }
```

Or to get from (n) defined types:

```json
  {
    "types": ["TYPE_1", "TYPE_2", "PUT_ALL_YOUR_DESIRED_TYPES_HERE"]
  }
```

And if you want to exclude messages containing a third type like `TYPE_3`, you can do:

```json
  {
    "types": [{"anything-but": "TYPE_3"}]
  }
```

Hope this helps...

Util links:

- [Amazon SNS subscription filter policies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-subscription-filter-policies.html)

Comment: Hi Renan thanks for the answer. It does help, however the scenario I have I cannot change the message body nor attributes. So I was wondering if I could filter based on the `MessageBody` (the ones I gave as an example above)

Comment: I understand. Maybe you can put a layer between this SQS and your process, like a AWS Lambda, making in the Lambda your body based filter em re-publish it in another queue.